# zdb.Connect: zdb requires SQLite 3.35.0 or newer

Tags: 20.04, sqlite, golang

I'm trying to install [goatcounter](https://github.com/arp242/goatcounter) on Ubuntu 20.04.

There's no help at Github goatcounter issues https://github.com/arp242/goatcounter/issues

I'm getting the error "zdb.Connect: zdb requires SQLite 3.35.0 or newer; have """

Is this a Ubuntu error? How do I determine what is causing this error?

goatcounter is extracted and installed; I did not build it from source.

SQLite3 3.38.3 is installed and runs.
`sqlite3 --version` returns 3.38.3 2022-04-27 12:03:15

I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64861331/how-can-i-install-or-upgrade-to-sqlite-3-33-0-on-ubuntu-18-04

Go and libzdb-dev are installed.

`ldd /usr/local/bin/goatcounter` returns "not a dynamic executable"

`goatcounter version` returns
"version=dev; go=go1.17.6; GOOS=linux; GOARCH=amd64; race=false; cgo=true"

`systemctl status --no-page -l goatcounter` returns

```
 goatcounter.service - GoatCounter
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/goatcounter.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-05-21 09:49:53 MDT; 7min ago
   Process: 83524 ExecStart=/usr/bin/env goatcounter serve -db sqlite3:///home/root/db/goatcounter.sqlite3 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 83524 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    
    May 21 09:49:53 localhost systemd[1]: goatcounter.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    May 21 09:49:53 localhost systemd[1]: goatcounter.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    May 21 09:49:53 localhost systemd[1]: goatcounter.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
    May 21 09:49:53 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped GoatCounter.
    May 21 09:49:53 localhost systemd[1]: goatcounter.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
    May 21 09:49:53 localhost systemd[1]: goatcounter.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    May 21 09:49:53 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start GoatCounter.
```

Comment: How did you install SQLite3 3.38.3 ? Which version of goatcounter?

Comment: The downloadable goatcounter releases are static binaries and do not need any additional libraries. Did you build goatcounter from source? Add output of `ldd /path/to/goatcoutner` to the question.

Comment: Thanks, details added in question

Comment: systemctl has cut the lines. Please try `systemctl status --no-page -l goatcounter`

Comment: That's added....

Comment: I checked, the static binary does not use any external libraries. I don't even have SQLite or Go or `libzdb-dev` installed and it runs. Was the sqlite database created from a previous version of goatcounter?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to install several times. Should I delete SQLite or the databases?

Comment: If you upgrade goatcounter from version 1.X you need to migrate the database: `goatcounter serve -automigrate -db sqlite3+/home/root/db/goatcounter.sqlite3`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136483/discussion-between-marco-and-bluedogranch).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and it turned goatcounter did not have permission to create the SQLite database file - the error message was just really misleading! I set proper write permissions for the target directory and everything started working. I only figured this out after [reading an old reply on the GitHub issues](https://github.com/arp242/goatcounter/issues/600#issuecomment-1147313168).

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>GoatCounter</kbd>  is service (mean it's Run all time )

Frist Download and Build

```bsh
$ cd ~
$ mkdir GoatCounter
$ git clone -b release-2.2 https://github.com/arp242/goatcounter.git
$ cd GoatCounter
$ go build -ldflags="-X zgo.at/goatcounter/v2.Version=$(git log -n1 --format='%h_%cI')" ./cmd/goatcounter
```

⬆️This above source command from Github⬆️

Then start GoatCounter By service

`systemctl start goatcounter`

then

`systemctl status goatcounter`

Then work well

...

---

### Work Well 
Thank

Answer (score 1):

After discussion in chat it was solved in two ways.

1. the port 443 was used by apache already.
2. the database seemed to be from an previous version of goatcounter, which needed migration (or start with a new database).

Using this command started goatcounter without error:

```
goatcounter serve -automigrate -db sqlite3+/home/root/db/goatcounter.sqlite3 -listen localhost:9999
```

The upcoming question was "how to use goatcounter as a subdomain on port 443?" But this has to be answered in a different question.